# How to resolve this installation error in colab?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, auto-sklearn

Once I run this code:

```
!pip install auto-sklearn
```

I get this error:

```
    Collecting auto-sklearn
      Downloading auto-sklearn-0.15.0.tar.gz (6.5 MB)
         ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 6.5/6.5 MB 16.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
      Installing build dependencies ... done
      Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
      Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
    Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from auto-sklearn) (67.7.2)
    Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from auto-sklearn) (4.7.1)
    Requirement already satisfied: distro in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from auto-sklearn) (1.7.0)
    Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.9.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from auto-sklearn) (1.23.5)
    Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=1.7.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from auto-sklearn) (1.10.1)
    Requirement already satisfied: joblib in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from auto-sklearn) (1.3.2)
    Collecting scikit-learn<0.25.0,>=0.24.0 (from auto-sklearn)
      Downloading scikit-learn-0.24.2.tar.gz (7.5 MB)
         ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 7.5/7.5 MB 45.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
      Installing build dependencies ... done
      Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
      error: subprocess-exited-with-error
      
      × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
      │ exit code: 1
      ╰─> See above for output.
      
      note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
    error: metadata-generation-failed
    
    × Encountered error while generating package metadata.
    ╰─> See above for output.
    
    note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
    hint: See above for details.
```

I tried installing various dependencies too while looking on to the documentation but didn't solved my problem.